# In TagBar plugin in Vim, automatically set cursorline

Tags: vim, tagbar

The question is really simple, when i run TagbarToggle i want the cursorline option to be True in that window (if it is in the "main" window).

something like:

```
if &cursorline
    call set_cursorline_in_tagbar()
endif
```

Of course i could just set it manually every time, but that's just not the Vim way.

Answer (score 1):

[It looks like](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar/blob/master/autoload/tagbar.vim#L1702) TagBar sets its own `FileType`: `tagbar`, this could be used in an `autocmd`:

```
autocmd FileType tagbar setlocal cursorline
```

Another option would be to set a custom highlighting for TagBar's own syntax groups that fits your need, [as shown in the documentation.](https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar/blob/master/doc/tagbar.txt#L504)

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that i fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it, for some reason TagBar sets nocursorline in the initWindow() function
I simply replaced it with cul. And now everything is working as it should.

> ***But why would he set nocursorline?***

Comment: I've now removed the code that disables cursorline and cursorcolumn. I originally thought that it would be more useful this way, but I guess that's not really true.